# Get the integer from BigDecimal

Tags: java

If I have a BigDecimal with value `6.54`, how do I convert that to an integer value of `654`? i.e. no decimal point.

`intValue()` will just convert to 6.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`BigDecimal.unscaledValue()` will return a `BigInteger` with the value `654`.  You could then call `intValue()` to convert that to an `int`, if you needed that specifically.